# Unit-testing AngularJS controller with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, electron

I have a perfectly functional app running with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), and [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) to do the testing. I am able to do tests on the DOM elements, but I can't manage to find a way to test the functions I have in my controller. I get this error message

> Failures:
>
> 1) app-controller.js encountered a declaration exception
>    Message:
>        ReferenceError: window is not defined
>      Stacktrace:
>        ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at Object. (/home/yann/workspace/hacker-keyboard/node_modules/angular/angular.js:28902:4)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at Object. (/home/yann/workspace/hacker-keyboard/node_modules/angular/index.js:1:63)

I've looked at a lot of posts, [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing), but I haven't found a solution to my problem.
Here are the files I'm using for testing:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'appController'
]);

var controllerModule = angular.module('appController', []);
```

**app-controller.js**

```
controllerModule.controller('appController', ['$scope',
    '$timeout',
    '$window',
    '$interval',
    '$filter',
    function ($scope, $timeout, $window, $interval, $filter){
    /* controller code here */
    }]);
```

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['test-spec.js'],
    capabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
        chromeOptions: {
            binary: "./dist/myApp-linux-x64/myApp"
        }
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.resetUrl = "file://";
    }
};
```

**test-spec.js**

```
describe('app-controller.js', function () {
    require('angular');
    require('angular-mocks');

    var scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller("appController", {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should return empty string',
            function () {
                var result = scope.fooFunction(12, 'blue');
                expect(result).toEqual("");
            });
});
```

Do you guys have any clue of what I missed/misunderstood?

***EDIT***
Because I am not in an Angular file, I don't have access to the `window` object. The requiring of `angular` and `angular-mocks` causes the error because it can not access to the `window` object. Does any one know how I can link it into my **test-spec.js** file?

Answer (score 2):

I see error

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

may be some problem this injection?

I give you my working config file. I use framework Jasmine.

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 55000,
specs: ['e2e/*-spec.js'],
framework: 'jasmine2',
baseUrl: /*<baseUrl>*/"http://url.com"/*</baseUrl>*/ ,
onPrepare: function() {
    var TeamCityReporter = require('jasmine-reporters').TeamCityReporter;
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new TeamCityReporter());
    var disableNgAnimate = function() {
        angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(['$animate', function($animate) {
            $animate.enabled(false);
            var style = ".ngdialog-content,.ngdialog-overlay,.ngdialog-closing .ngdialog-content,.ngdialog-closing .ngdialog-overlay {  animation-duration: 0ms!important;}";
            $("<style>" + style + "</style>").appendTo("head");
        }]);
    };
    browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);

    // Store the name of the browser that's currently being used.
    browser.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
        browser.params.browser = caps.get('browserName');
    });
},
```

};

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with Angular, I actually would suggest not using Protractor for what you're trying to do. Protractor is designed specifically to load a browser via Selenium, and to perform tests similar to a manual test in a browser that a human user might perform -- type into a form, click "Submit", check what page you're on, see if an alert or message is visible, etc.

If you want to specifically test a function or controller, you should use a unit testing framework such as karma. Karma supports mocking backend calls as well as controllers and modules, so you can isolate your controller's functionality in a test without having to run selenium or a browser (which also are unnecessary to execute a function for unit testing).

Another reason for not using protractor for unit tests is speed. Loading and executing small bits of code is MUCH faster than spinning up a server, a browser, drivers, loading pages, etc. I have E2E Protractor test suites that run and take 20+ minutes to run. Which is fine - the manual test pass is longer, but the difference in time can be a factor, too.

**Gotchas**  The exact configuration of tests can depend on what version of Angular you are using, so be careful at what docs and examples you use. Secondly, Karma is very picky about what files you load - EVERY vendor or application file you want to use at all must be loaded, and it must be loaded in the correct order in the karma.conf.js file.

To illustrate, here is how I would setup a unit test like what you’re trying to do in Karma with Jasmine:

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    basePath: ‘’,
    frameworks: [‘jasmine’],
    // In Karma, you MUST load both your application files, and then after
    // your test/spec files. It doesn’t run in a browser, so it will only execute
    // code that is directly loaded.
    files: [
        // Notice the load order is required vendors, then dependencies, then the app module
        // which requires the dependencies…
        ‘js/vendor/jquery’,
        ‘js/vendor/angular’,
        ‘js/vendor/angular-mocks’,  // if you want to use angular-mocks, include it!

        ‘js/app-controller.js’,
        ‘js/app.js’,
    ],

    reporters: [‘progress’],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    browsers: [‘Chrome’],
    plugins: [‘karma-jasmine’, ‘karma-chrome-launcher’],
    singleRun: true // run only once, then quit tests
}
```

**test-spec.js**

```
describe(‘app-controller.js’, function() {

    var appController;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module(‘app’);
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        appController = $controller(‘appController’);
    }));

    it(‘should return an empty string’, function() {
        var result = appController.fooFunction(12, 'blue');
        expect(result).toEqual("");
    })
})
```

As a second not about “window” not being recognized, it depends on the running context of your test environment. “window” is a JavaScript global that, inside of a browser, is always known because it’s a built in definition. Inside of Angular, though, windows means nothing - but Angular does have a provider “$window” which provides access to window from within an Angular app (since your control injects this, you probably know this already).
I see in your config the reset URL is “file://“ — a warning there is if you load files via the FILE protocol and not HTTP, the browser won’t think to run JavaScript, because it thinks it’s just reading a text document.

I hope that helps!